# syncing users with LDAP in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openldap

Hello I'm trying to connect my openLdap to keycloak
the configuration via user Federation seems to be ok (facing no errors  with test Connection and athentication)
but still, when i'm trying to Synchronize all users I have :
(Success! Sync of users finished successfully. 0 imported users, 0 updated users)
did I miss something during the configuration?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try Search Scope "one level" and User DN can you replace users by Users.

Comment: hello @dreamcrash thank you  for the comment . I tried your advice but still have the same problem

Comment: What are the object classes of your users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You areusing the wrong Attribute-Names. You should try "Other" as "Vendor" in your config.